# master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(HashBytes('MD5','text') replacement in SparkSQL

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark-sql

I have a code in SQL to generate strong ID by combining more columns from source table.

```
master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(HashBytes('MD5','test'))
```

Is there any replacement in SparkSQl returns the same results?

I have tried with

```
hex(md5('test'))
```

but this is not returning code in hexadecimal form.

Comment: FYI, from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) on `HASHBYTES`: *"The MD2, MD4, MD5, SHA, and SHA1 algorithms are deprecated starting with SQL Server 2016 (13.x). Use SHA2_256 or SHA2_512 instead. Older algorithms will continue working, but they will raise a deprecation event."* You should really avoid using MD5 in new work.

Comment: I don't know enough Spark to answer, but the functionality of the undocumented `fn_varbintohexstr` function has been replaced (since SQL Server 2008) with the `CONVERT` function. If you read up on that, especially the [`Binary Styles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#binary-styles) section, it might give you more information to search on.